# Display users email address on form thank-you page

Tags: php, html, css

I'm creating a forms thank-you page, the thank-you page will read:

```
<p>An activation link is being sent to your email address <b>custom-email@gmail.com</b>. If you do not receive it, please check your spam filter. </p>
```

I want their email address to appear on the thank-you page (where custom-email@gmail.com shows above).

What code do I need to put, to show this? The form is coded with PHP and can be seen at:

```
http://www.workbooks.com/sign-up/free-edition
```

Many thanks,

Sam

Comment: Either in the `$_POST` or `$_GET` superglobals depending on what method your form has. E.g `<form method="post">` is in `$_POST`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are answers with suggestions to output directly from $_POST/$_GET but that would be unsafe, particularly if you don't know how well validated the user input has been up to that point. Rule 1 of dealing with user input - it is dangerous and you should never trust it.

At the very least run it through a basic PHP string sanitization function like filter_input. So something like:

```
<p>An activation link is being sent to your email address <b><?php echo filter_input(INPUT_POST,'email',FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ; ?></b>. If you do not receive it, please check your spam filter.</p>
```

If the input was not a valid email address you'll get "false" coming out there but it's infinitely better than allowing the user to put whatever they want on the page.

Comment: Thanks, form should be validated so the false shouldn't ever appear!

Answer (score 1):

E-mail address is in POST/GET, depending on `method` you are using to send a form.

Answer (score 1):

simply echo the posted form value:

```
<p>An activation link is being sent to your email address <b><?php echo $_POST['email'] ; ?></b>. If you do not receive it, please check your spam filter. </p>
```

This example is based on the fact that the input field for email has the name "email"

Comment: Don't do this. Don't echo $_POST data without sanitizing it first. At the very least run it through filter_input.

Comment: Thanks, will this work on an .html thank-you page or will I need to make it a .php page?

Comment: That depends on you server setup, but most servers are capable of serving php through html files aswell. So the short answer to your question is, yes it can be served in a .html file

Comment: @HeatherEMSL why shouldnt he echo out the content of a $_POST parameter before sanitizing it? There is a difference between echoing the content, and running a sql query with it.

Comment: It allows the user to run any JavaScript based on your domain, opening you up to XSS attacks.

Comment: A visitor might just aswell run javascript on your domain without posting anything to it at all. Just use a developer tool in the browser.

Comment: Fair point, but my general policy is "no matter how simple the situation, do not trust user input".

Answer (score 0):

Its is very simple.You need to just add `<?php echo $_POST['email'] ; ?>` So it will print the **Email Address**.

So according to your answer it will be something like this :

`<p>An activation link is being sent to your email address <b><?php echo $_POST['email'] ; ?></b>. If you do not receive it, please check your spam filter. </p>`

**Note**: You need to have thanks file in with `.php` extension.